# Django - reverse query name clash

Tags: django, django-models

I put a circular Foreign Key in Django which has resulted in a name clash. I don't understand why it's clashing or how best to remedy.  (This is the first time I've had a circular reference in models - so I'm not sure if that may be the root cause of the issue?)

For the below:

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    rating = models.FloatField(null=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    default_tariff = models.ForeignKey('Tariff')

class Tariff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    payment_method = models.ManyToManyField(PaymentMethod) 
    region = models.ManyToManyField(Region)
```

The error is:

> Reverse query name for 'Supplier.default_tariff' clashes with field
>   name 'Tariff.supplier'.
>           HINT: Rename field 'Tariff.supplier', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field
>   'Supplier.default_tariff'.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To avoid this you can use the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    rating = models.FloatField(null=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    default_tariff = models.ForeignKey('Tariff', related_name='+')

class Tariff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    payment_method = models.ManyToManyField(PaymentMethod) 
    region = models.ManyToManyField(Region)
```

Edit from the comments:

When you set related_name="+" Django does not create a backwards relation. In this case, Tariff will not have a backwards relation to the Supplier model.

Comment: and what does `related_name="+"` do? apart from fixing the error, what happens? what stops working?

Comment: @Toskan It chages the way you call the relationship.

Comment: This is a horrible answer, doesn't address why the error happens nor does it explain how this solves it.

Comment: @Silidrone Hi, avoid horrible comments and complement the answer with missing information. Cherrs!

Comment: Yeah you're right, I was frustrated at the time, sorry.

Comment: Short explanation: when you set `related_name="+"` Django does not create a backwards relation. In this case, `Tariff` will not have a backwards relation to the `Supplier` model

Comment: Does not explain what is clashing with what, what is the root cause, which was the original posters question.

Answer (score 5):

The error message is a pretty correct statement on its own (you have omitted the error code given in the output, I think it was 'E303'), but we need to understand what it actually means.

I will not ask why don't you use Many-to-many relationship in this case, let's focus on how "backward" object relations work:

Example:

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

**Following relationships “backward”**

One-to-many relationship does not exist in a "forward" manner because it is the "many side", that holds the key, but Django creates API accessors for the “other” side of the relationship – the link from the related model to the model that defines the relationship. For example, a Blog object b has access to a list of all related Entry objects via the entry_set attribute: `b.entry_set.all()`.

...

If a model has a ForeignKey, instances of the foreign-key model will have access to a [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/managers/#manager-names) that returns all instances of the first model. By default, this Manager is named FOO_set, where FOO is the source model name, lowercased. This Manager returns QuerySets, which can be filtered and manipulated as described in the “Retrieving objects” section above.

Follow the [documentation link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) for more info/examples.

It's because of these API accessors **['related_name'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)** (complement this information with [related_name in Abstract Classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-related-name)) was implemented, to avoid naming collisions between field names and

1. accessor_name(which would be the name of the manager),
   and/or
2. query_name (which is the model name))

**Let's take a look at the Django code for better understanding:**

[This](https://github.com/django/django/blob/02bc7161ec477afd4a7b328936eb8adac078d7b9/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L198) is where your error comes from:

```
def _check_clashes(self):
    """Check accessor and reverse query name clashes."""
    from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

    errors = []
    opts = self.model._meta

    # `f.remote_field.model` may be a string instead of a model. Skip if model name is
    # not resolved.
    if not isinstance(self.remote_field.model, ModelBase):
        return []

    # Consider that we are checking field `Model.foreign` and the models
    # are:
    #
    #     class Target(models.Model):
    #         model = models.IntegerField()
    #         model_set = models.IntegerField()
    #
    #     class Model(models.Model):
    #         foreign = models.ForeignKey(Target)
    #         m2m = models.ManyToManyField(Target)

    # rel_opts.object_name == "Target"
    rel_opts = self.remote_field.model._meta
    # If the field doesn't install a backward relation on the target model
    # (so `is_hidden` returns True), then there are no clashes to check
    # and we can skip these fields.
    rel_is_hidden = self.remote_field.is_hidden()
    rel_name = self.remote_field.get_accessor_name()  # i. e. "model_set"
    rel_query_name = self.related_query_name()  # i. e. "model"
    # i.e. "app_label.Model.field".
    field_name = '%s.%s' % (opts.label, self.name)

    # Check clashes between accessor or reverse query name of `field`
    # and any other field name -- i.e. accessor for Model.foreign is
    # model_set and it clashes with Target.model_set.
    potential_clashes = rel_opts.fields + rel_opts.many_to_many
    for clash_field in potential_clashes:
        # i.e. "app_label.Target.model_set".
        clash_name = '%s.%s' % (rel_opts.label, clash_field.name)
        if not rel_is_hidden and clash_field.name == rel_name:
            errors.append(
                checks.Error(
                    "Reverse accessor for '%s' clashes with field name '%s'." % (field_name, clash_name),
                    hint=("Rename field '%s', or add/change a related_name "
                          "argument to the definition for field '%s'.") % (clash_name, field_name),
                    obj=self,
                    id='fields.E302',
                )
            )

        if clash_field.name == rel_query_name:
            errors.append(
                checks.Error(
                    "Reverse query name for '%s' clashes with field name '%s'." % (field_name, clash_name),
                    hint=("Rename field '%s', or add/change a related_name "
                          "argument to the definition for field '%s'.") % (clash_name, field_name),
                    obj=self,
                    id='fields.E303',
                )
            )

    # Check clashes between accessors/reverse query names of `field` and
    # any other field accessor -- i. e. Model.foreign accessor clashes with
    # Model.m2m accessor.
    potential_clashes = (r for r in rel_opts.related_objects if r.field is not self)
    for clash_field in potential_clashes:
        # i.e. "app_label.Model.m2m".
        clash_name = '%s.%s' % (
            clash_field.related_model._meta.label,
            clash_field.field.name,
        )
        if not rel_is_hidden and clash_field.get_accessor_name() == rel_name:
            errors.append(
                checks.Error(
                    "Reverse accessor for '%s' clashes with reverse accessor for '%s'." % (field_name, clash_name),
                    hint=("Add or change a related_name argument "
                          "to the definition for '%s' or '%s'.") % (field_name, clash_name),
                    obj=self,
                    id='fields.E304',
                )
            )

        if clash_field.get_accessor_name() == rel_query_name:
            errors.append(
                checks.Error(
                    "Reverse query name for '%s' clashes with reverse query name for '%s'."
                    % (field_name, clash_name),
                    hint=("Add or change a related_name argument "
                          "to the definition for '%s' or '%s'.") % (field_name, clash_name),
                    obj=self,
                    id='fields.E305',
                )
            )

    return errors
```

[This](https://github.com/django/django/blob/02bc7161ec477afd4a7b328936eb8adac078d7b9/django/db/models/fields/reverse_related.py#L180) is how the accessor_name is born

```
def get_accessor_name(self, model=None):
    # This method encapsulates the logic that decides what name to give an
    # accessor descriptor that retrieves related many-to-one or
    # many-to-many objects. It uses the lowercased object_name + "_set",
    # but this can be overridden with the "related_name" option. Due to
    # backwards compatibility ModelForms need to be able to provide an
    # alternate model. See BaseInlineFormSet.get_default_prefix().
    opts = model._meta if model else self.related_model._meta
    model = model or self.related_model
    if self.multiple:
        # If this is a symmetrical m2m relation on self, there is no reverse accessor.
        if self.symmetrical and model == self.model:
            return None
    if self.related_name:
        return self.related_name
    return opts.model_name + ('_set' if self.multiple else '')
```

and this is the query_name (also in related.py)

```
def related_query_name(self):
    """
    Define the name that can be used to identify this related object in a
    table-spanning query.
    """
    return self.remote_field.related_query_name or self.remote_field.related_name or self.opts.model_name
```

Now, that you know how the naming is done and what the reverse relationship is, you'll understand why

> Reverse query name for 'Supplier.default_tariff' clashes with field name 'Tariff.supplier'.

And how to solve it:

> HINT: Rename field 'Tariff.supplier', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Supplier.default_tariff'.

Hope that helps. I just was working on a *related* issue ))

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following solution.It works for django==3.

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    rating = models.FloatField(null=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    default_tariff = models.ForeignKey('Tariff', related_name="%(class)s_tarriff")
```