# What exactly the reverse query name in its related model in Django?

Tags: django

I got pretty much the same problem as in [Django - reverse query name clash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003865/django-reverse-query-name-clash).

for the following code:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    featured_product = models.ForeignKey(
        'Product', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

There will be an error saying:

```
store.Category.featured_product: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'store.Category.featured_product' clashes with field name 'store.Product.category'.
```

I know it the `featured_product`in `Category` should add`related_name="+"` to avoid this error.  But since this is a many-to-one case, and I think the reverse query name for `store.Category.featured_product`in`Product`class should be `store.Product.category_set` so it shouldn't have a conflict with `store.Product.category`.

Comment: Please give a proper example that actually reproduces your problem... Firstly this would give an error because you haven't specified `on_delete` for the foreign keys (It is a _required_ argument). Next it won't be `Supplier.default_tariff_set` it will be `Supplier.tariff_set` or if you have set the `related_name` or the `related_query_name` then it will be that.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I've edited it again and please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if there weren't outright clashes (with the snippet you have, the generated reverse accessors should be `Product.category_set` and `Category.product_set`), I'd say Django is trying to be helpful so you don't make mistakes regarding the reverse accessors down the line.

As you noted, you can set `related_name='+'` to not create the reverse accessor at all, but I'd probably name the reverse accessor something like `related_name='featured_product_for_categories'`.

After all, your data model does make it possible for a product to be featured in multiple categories, and even categories it isn't part of.